# Deja-dup local restore fails, waiting for Google config

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup

I backed up from Ubuntu 16.04 to a USB hard drive using Deja-Dup.  Following a system crash I tried to restore the data files to my new system drive running 18.04.

Deja-Dup offers a choice of backup locations including the USB drive as well as the option to choose a Local backup folder within that drive.
 Either way, I get the error message, `Storage location not available` with the explanation, `Waiting for Google to be configured in your backup settings...`.

I do not understand what Google has to do with a local, cabled connection. How can I recover the backed up files?

Comment: Hello Graham93 , and Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In order to increase that chances that somebody gives a good answer to your question, the first thing to do is ask a question; you should edit your post and actually include a question. You should also clarify the context: who gives that error message? When does it give that error message? What are you doing in order to make that error message appear? Is the error message unexpected? If so, what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Although I like Deja-dup, it's not transparent at all, and the error messages are lacking. Based on my experiences with it, I would guess that the permissions on your USB hard drive may be the problem.